# Arduino + UltraSensor - Serial Monitor outputs garbage

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-sr04

I am trying to connect an HC-SR04 to an Arduino Uno. For some reason when I run this code on the serial monitor it outputs wingdings in a straight line.

ýòøÿüÿøÿüòý÷ÿ÷ýÿÿúýÿýúÿòý÷ûòûòû÷ýÿøÿøÿÿ÷øÿüÿýÿþòøòÿÿøûüÿøÿÿòÿ÷ûòûòý÷ûòûòûöû÷ÿûû÷øÿÿ÷øÿüÿýÿüÿûöþÿý÷ûòûòûòûöûûûûûò

No breaks. Sometimes when I hit "Tools/Fix Encoding and Reload" it outputs

Ping: 0 cm
Ping: 0 cm
Ping: 0 cm

followed by more wingdings.

I've looked up some similar problems and it was usually fixed by changing baud to a lower value, 9600. I've done this and I still have problems.

Would you be able to help me out? I'd very much appreciate it.

```
const int trigpin = 9;
const int echopin = 10;
long duration;
int distance;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  pinMode(trigpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echopin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigpin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echopin,HIGH);
  distance = duration *0.034/2;
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);
}
```

**Updated Solution**

After testing out Joel's code to check the sensor was in order, I found some new sample code which worked to display the distance in inches of a HC SR04 sensor.

```
  // set up variables

  int trigpin = 13; // Trig Pin is connected to Arduino pin 13
  int echopin = 11; // Echo Pin is connected to Arduino pin 11



 // now we need variables which we will be measuring

 float pingtime; // Time for ping to travel to target and return
 float targetdistance; // Distance from sensor to target
 float speedofsound = 776.5; // speed of sound in miles per hour at 77 F



void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); // Turn on serial port
pinMode(trigpin, OUTPUT); // Sensor trig pin is output
pinMode(echopin, INPUT); // input is reading from echopin


 }

void loop() {
digitalWrite(trigpin, LOW);// set trigger pin low
delayMicroseconds(2000); // pause to let signal settle
digitalWrite(trigpin, HIGH); // set trigger pin high 
delayMicroseconds(15); // pause in high state, make sure sensor reads
digitalWrite(trigpin, LOW); // bring trigpin back low

   pingtime = pulseIn(echopin, HIGH); 

// sensor will be sending HIGH pulse, measure pingtime at echopin
// ping time is in microseconds

  pingtime = pingtime / 1000000.; 

// converts pingtime to seconds because speed of sound is miles per hour


  pingtime = pingtime / 3600.; 
  // converts pingtime to hours
  // add a period to make float to avoid int mistakes


  targetdistance = speedofsound * pingtime;
  // calculates distance in miles traveled by ping

  targetdistance = targetdistance / 2; 
  // accounts for roundtrip of ping to target

  targetdistance = targetdistance * 63360.;
  // convert target distance to inches
  // 63360 inches in a mile

Serial.print("The distance to the target is:");
Serial.print(targetdistance);
Serial.println("inches");
delay(1000);

 }
```

Comment: since it seems that the problem did have to do with the serial monitor settings, can you please select my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your serial monitor baud rate. This is definitely caused by your serial monitor being set to a different baud rate than the 9600 you specified in the program.

If it had anything to do with the sensor than this line would be printed properly `Serial.print("Distance: ");`

Once you change the serial monitor baud rate then try running this program, to verify that it is set properly:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Hi There!");
}
```

If that prints "Hi There!" then the program your serial monitor is set up properly.

Comment: I tested your code and I get an infinite loop of "Hi There"s which I will take as a good sign. :D

Comment: @AngelaAlbrecht that is a good sign, try your original code again without changing any settings and see if it prints "Distance: "